# Navbar image trouble

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple of problems with my nav bar.  Basically I have 5 options on my nav bar,  the first 3 are in text format, then last two are images that you can click on (a phone number and a live chat).  Both are png files, and all items are within  tags.

The problem I have though is that the images appear slightly above the nav bar.  Basically if you ran a horizontal line along the text on the nav bar options then the text in the logo's is slightly above where it should be.

So how can I make the image navbar options appear slightly higher?

My 2nd Question is that one of the logo's also needs to have text appear over it (the phone number) and I have no idea how to do this.  How do I put text over an image within a nav bar?

Comment: which Bootstrap version? also show your current markup, preferably in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

you can play around with css for your first problem, add something like the following to your css file:

```
.navbar img { padding-top:10px }
```

For the second question, have a look at [tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips)

Comment: Yes!! Thankyou Kmae - that has solved the first part!!  Thank you so much for this, you have ended my search and ripping my hair out lol.  I will look for the second part on the link you have suggested.  thanks again :)

Comment: Glad I could help, please accept the answer then so this question can be archived as solved. Good luck with the tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

without jsfiddle, can't give exact answer..but you can try margin-left, margin-top and give minus values to it